# isScreenOn() returning true when screen is off

Tags: android, android-screen

I am trying to detect if the screen is off. Tried with `BroadcastReceiver` but didn't work as expected.

So i tried with Power manager `isScreenOn()` in `onPause()` and it works great.
But i noticed that when i press the power button to lock the screen and then immediately press it again to unlock it, `isScreenOn()` returns true.

Can you help me?

I can't find solution around this.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //registBroadcastReceiver();

    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    boolean isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn();

    if (!isScreenOn) {
        Log.d("Screen", "OFF");
        flag1 = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your question? If isScreenOn() isnt called than you can't say that it's not working properly.

Comment: the problem is that isScreenOn is not called only if i press the power button twice in a row

Comment: did u managed to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this link to the Android Developer's Guide:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isInteractive()

```
isScreenOn()
```

doesn't check if the screen is on or off, but rather whether or not it's interactive.

"The value returned by this method only indicates whether the device is in an interactive state which may have nothing to do with the screen being on or off. To determine the actual state of the screen, use getState()."

Comment: Either way the screen is not Interactive and it still returns true

Comment: Did you do a call to isInteractive and found that it returned false?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html:

> isScreenOn()
>   This method was deprecated in API level 20. Use isInteractive() instead.